# apache beam avroIO read api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, apache-beam

I am using apache beam avroIO to read about a million files. Is there any ordering guarantees of the records read by the avroIO or can i consider them well shuffled ? After reading those files i need to shuffle the data around (which can be quite expensive and time consuming if being done for multiple days) , but is it the same as shuffling the files instead and then reading them ? I know shuffling the files is not the complete shuffle as i wont be shuffling records within the file but i can live with good enough shuffle at the file level so want to understand when avroIO reads millions of files, does internally it uses any kind of ordering file creation timestamp , or lexically sorting file names ? Also I can see that avroIO.ReadAll transform internally does a reshuffle of the all the files , so is it necessary that i need to another shuffle of my data given that file level shuffling may be good enough for my use case ?

Is there a good way in apache beam to ensure that i can read shuffled data directly rather than have to flatten them into multiple billion records and then use groupby which is slow even with shuffle service and expensive as well.

Comment: Can you describe more about your application use-case? What do you want to accomplish by shuffling the data? `PCollections` in Apache Beam are unordered, and so you should not make any assumptions about the ordering or randomization of data.

Comment: just shuffling a training data for training our models. the data is stored in millions of files on gcs buckets , so i want to shuffle the training data for training some models. I can live with approximate shuffle i.e i see ReadALL basically internally calls shuffle of all the partition splits created from all matched files.

Answer (score 1):

`AvroIO` doesn't make any guarantees about shuffling of the data. The Apache Beam SDK is open source, so as you alluded it's possible to [read through the implementation](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.4.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.java). It looks like [file ranges get randomized](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ae2e12ac3c7dcc3831b185407853331f5d383e0c/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/ReadAllViaFileBasedSource.java#L63), however this is an implementation detail of the transform implementation. If your application requires shuffled data, I recommend adding an explicit `Reshuffle` instead of relying on internal details.